# prevent form's resubmission on back and reload events - HTML

Tags: php, html

I have a form in my html code and on submitting the form, php code from the same file is executed, the php code shows some error messages if form is not properly filled (if any field is empty), I want to prevent those error messages when user reload the page or when user goes back to that page, I simply want to show the form on reload and back events. For doing that I written this code but this code does not shows the form on clicking browser's back button secondly this code does not prevents error message on reloading the page and I want to achieve both the tasks kindly help.

**this is my code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Example</title>
    </head>
    <form method="POST" action="<?php echo ($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])?>">
        Username <input type="text" name="username"/>
        Password <input type="password" name="password"/>
        <input type="submit" name="login" value="Login"/>
    </form>
    <?php
        header("Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); // HTTP 1.1.
        header("Pragma: no-cache"); // HTTP 1.0.
        header("Expires: 0 "); // Proxies.
        if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST") {
            $username = $_POST['username'];
            $password = $_POST['password'];
            if(empty($username)==true || empty($password)==true)
                echo '<script language="javascript">alert("Incomplete registration!")</script>';
            else {
                //my work
            }
        }
    ?>
</html>
```

Comment: Side note - You can't set the header there. You've already written text to `STDOUT`. Instead, perform all logic checking at the top of the page.

Comment: I think you need to do a POST-REDIRECT-GET